# Why can't I measure elapsed time using getTime() from java.util.Date class?

Tags: java, time

I want to measure time that a Java program needs to do something.

In book only the `java.util.Date` class was mentioned, so I assumed it was correct (or correct enough) to use it for solving this problem.

I have the following code:

```
 time.start();

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
array[i]=(int)(Math.random()*100000);

time.stop();
```

Where time.start() and time.stop are (in Java class):

```
Date timeMeasured = new Date();


    public void start(){
    startTime = timeMeasured.getTime();

}

public void stop(){
    endTime = timeMeasured.getTime();

}
```

After some research I find out that I should use System.currentTimeMillis() to measure time, and after trying it was working. My code just returned 0 every time.

Can someone explain why, and can you correct my code, no matter that it is wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Date object with default constructor, he will represent the time of creation.
So any call of `getTime()` will return the date of the creation of the object, NOT the current time.

Your code would work if instead of creating a global object you would had instantiate it every time before use, but then the time needed to create the object may screw up your calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.